# Meeting Room Booking System - RFID Card Reader

Tags: mysql, android-studio, rfid

I have a tablet running on android with rfid reader inbuilt in it. I was wondering how can i get the rfid tag from the reader to android studio where i am building my application.

This project is for a meeting room booking application. The inbuilt RFID is used to read the card number from an employee's card. It serves as a form of authentication whereby it is meant to check if the card belongs to an existing employee. The android studio serves as the front end, displaying to the user whether the room is successfully booked. Thus, i am interested in knowing how does the data flow from the rfid to the android studio.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a question? 'How does data flow?' seems a bit broad for SO

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how to parse the rfid card number to the database backend